# React component displays fine when I don't have it inside an onClick function. What could be wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Main file

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { MakeBoard } from './Board.js';
import { Login } from './Login.js';
import { Logout } from './Logout.js';
import { Display } from './Display.js';
import { LeaderBoard } from './LeaderBoard.js';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io();

function App() {
  
  
  //These are all of my variables for the game. Yeah, it's a lot.
  const [board, setBoard] = useState(["","","","","","","","",""]);
  const [users, setUser] = useState([]);
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [checkUser,setCheckUser] = useState(null);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [currentLetter, setCurrentLetter] = useState('Temp');
  const [isXNext, set_isXNext] = useState(true);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(null);
  var currentWindow;
  var logoutButton;
  var winner;
  var theWinnerIsStatement;
  var reset;
  var leaderBoardButton;
  var leader;

  //Use effects for the game. If the user reloads there page, it doesn't update to the original player's square, but instead updates the original player's square to be blank as well.
  useEffect(() =>{
    socket.on('tictactoe',(data)=>{
      setBoard(prevBoard=> [...data.message]);
      set_isXNext((prev) => !data.nxt);
      console.log(isXNext);
    });
  },[]);
  
  /*useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup(){
      socket.emit('logout',checkUser);
    }
  });*/
  
  useEffect(() =>{
    socket.on('login',(data) =>{
      setUser(prev => {
        const temp = [...data.users];
        console.log("Up-to-date list of users",temp);
        return temp;
      });
    });
    },[]);






  //Changes the value of each square. currentLetter is telling the program if the user is X or O.
  //It has nothing to do with the square's value. This function also tells the program if X is next.
  function onClickButton(clickedId){
    if(currentLetter != 'X' && currentLetter != 'O'){
      return null;
    }
    console.log(currentLetter,isXNext);
    if((isXNext && currentLetter==='X') || (!isXNext && currentLetter==='O')){
      console.log(clickedId);
      setBoard(prevBoard => {
        const temp = [...prevBoard];
        if(temp[parseInt(clickedId)]!='X' && temp[parseInt(clickedId)]!='O'){
          temp[parseInt(clickedId)]=currentLetter;
        }
        set_isXNext((prev)=>!isXNext);
        socket.emit('tictactoe',{message : temp,nxt : isXNext});
        return temp;
      });
      console.log(board);
    }
    
  }
  
  //Tells all the users who's logged in, tells the program who the current user is (i.e. the person who logged in on the current tab)
  function onLogin(){
    const user = inputRef.current.value;
    if (user===""){
      alert("You need to enter a proper username");
    }
    else{
      console.log("Current list of users upon login",users);
      setUser(prev => {
        const temp = [...prev,user];
        setCheckUser((prev)=>user);
        return temp;
      });
      setIsLoggedIn((prev)=>true);
      socket.emit('login',{user : user});
    }
  }

  //Wasn't required but I figured what the heck. Still isn't perfect.
  function onLogout(){
    setIsLoggedIn((prev) => false);
    setBoard(prevBoard => ["","","","","","","","",""]);
    socket.emit('tictactoe',{message : ["","","","","","","","",""]});
    setCheckUser((prev) => '');
    setCurrentLetter((prev) => '');
    set_isXNext((prev) => true);
    setUser((prev)=>[]);
    socket.emit('logout',checkUser);
    setCheckUser((prev) => null);
    console.log(checkUser);
  }
  
  //Tells the user if they're X, O or a spectator.
  function setUserLetter(number,name){
    console.log("This is the current index",number);
    console.log("This is the current user",name);
    console.log("And this is the client",checkUser);
    if(name===checkUser && number===0){
      console.log(name,number,checkUser);
      setCurrentLetter((prev) => 'X');
    }
    else if (name === checkUser && number===1){
      setCurrentLetter((prev) => 'O');
    }
  }
  
  function calculateWinner(squares) {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return "Player ".concat(squares[a]);
    }
  }
  return null;
  }
  
  //reset function. nxt is false because the listener for tictactoe sets isXNext to the opposite of nxt.
  function reset(){
    setBoard(prevBoard => ["","","","","","","","",""]);
    set_isXNext((prev) => true);
    socket.emit('tictactoe',{message : ["","","","","","","","",""], nxt : false});
  }
  
  function leaderBoard(){
    console.log("The leaderBoard button was clicked");
    leader = users.map((currentUser,index) => <Display name={currentUser} number={index}/>);  
  }
  
  
  
  
  //Conditionals
  if(!isLoggedIn){
    currentWindow = <Login inputRef={inputRef} onLogin={onLogin}/>;
    logoutButton = null;
    winner = null;
    theWinnerIsStatement=null;
    reset=null;
  }
  else{
    currentWindow = board.map((if_x,index) => <MakeBoard if_x={if_x} id={index} click={onClickButton}/>);
    logoutButton = <Logout onLogout={onLogout}/>;
    leaderBoardButton = <LeaderBoard leaderBoard={leaderBoard}/>;
    theWinnerIsStatement=<h1>The winner is: </h1>;
    winner = calculateWinner(board);
    reset = <button onClick={reset}>Reset</button>;
    
  }
  
  

  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="board">
        {currentWindow}
      </div>
      <div>
        {logoutButton}{reset}
      </div>
      <div>
        {leaderBoardButton}
        {leader}
      </div>
      <div>
        {theWinnerIsStatement}{winner}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Leaderboard.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

export function LeaderBoard(props){
    console.log("The leaderBoard file was opened");
    return( 
        <button onClick={props.leaderBoard}>Leader Board</button>
    );
}
```

Display.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';

export function Display(props){
    console.log("This is the current user",props.name,props.number);
    var letter='';
    if(props.number==0){
        letter='X';
    }
    else if (props.number==1){
        letter='O';
    }
    return(
        <ol>
            Player {letter} : {props.name}
        </ol>
        );
}
```

I'm basically just making a tic tac toe game. My program was able to display the leaderboard component before I put it inside of the event handler. My logs show that the program doesn't reach my Display.js file at all, and I can't discern why. Originally, I just had the leaderboard display immediately upon the page loading. But the problem requires that I create a button for displaying the leaderboard. Now I can't get it to display at all.

Comment: There is an awful lot of code here, too much imo for one component - and that's probably part of the problem. However, as far as I can tell, your actual problem is that you are updating a variable called `leader` and expecting that to cause a rerender of your component - but that is not how React works. If you make `leader` into a state variable (`const [leader, setLeader] = useState();` then use `setLeader` everytime you are currently doing `leader =`) this should start to work better.

Comment: But that worked before I added the button. Originally, the map function was inside the else statement. I had leader = users.map(...) and it rendered just fine.

Comment: Right, so it wasn't varying (except when the `users` state variable was updated) so didn't need to be in state. Your click event has introduced a way that it can independently vary, so it now needs to become part of the state. (It would probably be cleaner just to have a new boolean state variable which determines if the "leaderboard" is shown or not, and just toggle that from your click function. I've not spent enough time trying to understand your code to advise what is "best" - but whatever you do, you need state.)

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Yep, that worked. I feel so silly.